# How to textually indicate that there are no results in a SQL SELECT?

Tags: sql, select, count, case, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL `CASE` statement that doesn't appear to be evaluating the conditional correctly. This table currently is empty (0  non-null rows) so I would assume the `ELSE` condition should be true and therefore output the text string below. However it doesn't populate anything in the results.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN EC.INV_ITEM_ID <> '' THEN EC.INV_ITEM_ID
     ELSE 'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES'
     END
  
FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC
ORDER BY INV_ITEM_ID
```

Comment: If the table is empty, then the query returns no rows.  The `case` **expression** (NOT "statement") is not evaluated.

Comment: If the table has 0 rows, then the above `SELECT` will return nothing. A `CASE` expression can't return any rows, if there are *no rows*. The only simple SQL Statement that returns a result set, when there are no rows, is a `COUNT` without a `GROUP BY`. For example `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = N'If you have a table called this, you are being silly!';`

Comment: @Larnu so can I use `COUNT*` with a `Case` statement, or how else can I accomplish returning the text string if there a no rows present?

Comment: `CASE` **expression**; SQL Server has no support for `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: And you'll need to go be us more details to answer your question, such as what you expect when there are multiple rows.

Comment: If there is an INV_ITEM_ID (there always will be if there is a row present) then I want to just return that INV_ITEM_ID. The only time I want to return the above text string is if there is no INV_ITEM_ID / no rows in the table.

Comment: I think using `Case` with `Exists` as below will work fine for me: `SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC)
    THEN  'We Have Records of this Customer'
    ELSE  'We Do Not Have Records For This Customer'
    END AS 'result'`

Comment: No this still will not work, I want it to return the INV_ITEM_ID values if there is one / a row exists. It's only when there is not an INV_ITEM_ID / no rows present do I want it to return the text string.

Comment: you will have to handle that in your left join query - CASE just won't work as you expect in your query - unless you have EC.INV_ITEM_ID = '', only then you would get that text. On the other hand if you're doing left join then you would be able to do something like "SELECT <..> (CASE WHEN EC.INV_ITEM_ID IS NOT NULL THEN EC.INV_ITEM_ID ELSE 'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES' END) AS  INV_ITEM_ID   FROM someothertable  ST LEFT JOIN PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC on ST.somefield = EC.somefield"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC WHERE EC.INV_ITEM_ID <> '' AND EC.INV_ITEM_ID IS NOT NULL) > 0)
SELECT EC.INV_ITEM_ID FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC WHERE EC.INV_ITEM_ID <> '' AND EC.INV_ITEM_ID IS NOT NULL
ELSE
SELECT 'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES'
```

First line will calculate how many non empty rows there are in the table
second line will return a 1 column table with all the IDs that were not NULL or '' if any is found at all
4th row will return the default message if the table was actually empty

Answer (score 1):

All values in a column must have the same data type. So if the `INV_ITEM_ID` column is being used for a string value of `'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES'` in the case where there aren't any records then the column must have a textual data type.

If this isn't the case, you'll need to convert the IDs to strings to match this in the case where there are records. Personally I'd advise against this as it's like mixing chalk and cheese - a string value doesn't really belong in a numeric ID column - and even if the IDs happen to be strings it's still questionable as semantically the "no results" string isn't an ID.

But if you *really* want to do it, something like the following SQL can achieve it:

```
SELECT 'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES' AS INV_ITEM_ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC)
UNION ALL 
SELECT CAST(INV_ITEM_ID AS VARCHAR(26))
FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC
ORDER BY INV_ITEM_ID;
```

**Rextester demo:** https://rextester.com/FIRWF53864

Comment: A `NOT EXISTS` query would be easier to understand, IMHO: `SELECT 'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES' AS INV_ITEM_ID FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC)`

Comment: Agreed, thanks - have modified the answer accordingly. (Actually needed to omit the `FROM` clause as it causes no row to be present.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return records from an empty table. The case statement is being evaluated against every record in the table. When there are no records then there will be nothing to evaluate, thus the empty result set. There are a few ways to check for this condition. If the client is expecting a specific result set and will check a known field for the existence of data, (which seems hacky) then you can return similar shaped data from a derived result set with your messaging, however, **I would encourage you to think about checking for this condition at the consumer as database queries are better suited for inserting/updating/deleting and getting data**.

```
DECLARE @PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC TABLE(INV_ITEM_ID NVARCHAR(200))
--INSERT @PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC VALUES ('I''m Here')

IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT EC.INV_ITEM_ID FROM @PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC))
    SELECT INV_ITEM_ID =  'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES'
ELSE
SELECT 
CASE WHEN EC.INV_ITEM_ID <> '' THEN EC.INV_ITEM_ID
     ELSE 'EC.INV_ITEM_ID has an empty string for a value'
     END AS INV_ITEM_ID
  
FROM @PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC
ORDER BY INV_ITEM_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `CASE` is evaluated only for existant rows, if your table is empty you will get no record at all.

But, you want to get a record with a message even if the table is empty so you must create that row.
You can do it using `UNION` to add a new row to result set only when `PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC` is empty.

So, you can simply list all your records if there is any,
and show your message when `PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC` is empty.

```
SELECT EC.INV_ITEM_ID
FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC
ORDER BY INV_ITEM_ID

UNION ALL

SELECT 'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 'X' X FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC )
```

Pay attention, you need `INV_ITEM_ID` column to be of type char/varchar/nvarchar or you will get an error.
If your `INV_ITEM_ID` is a number you can use this workaround:

```
SELECT EC.INV_ITEM_ID, NULL Message
FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC
ORDER BY INV_ITEM_ID

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL INV_ITEM_ID, 'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES' Message
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 'X' X FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC )
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is a `relational` database. Relational databases works of off `sets`, which is basically a list of records. If there is no record, then your function / logic (`CASE` in this case) cannot be applied. If you need a record returned when your query returns zero record, then you need to provide a record from another source to be returned. One way of doing that is providing a record through `UNION` with a `WHERE` clause that guarantees a special record is returned when the result set is empty. When the result set is NOT empty, then `WHERE` clause makes sure this new record is not returned. The gotcha here is that, this special record has to have the same number of columns as the regular query result and with the same or compatible data types.

```
; WITH cte (
 ---- your complex query goes here 
  select colString, colNumeric 
   .............
) 
SELECT colString, colNumeric FROM cte 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'no result found' as colString, NULL as colNumeric  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte) --- this returns true only if no record in cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Common Table Expression (CTE), one for the main query (your query) and another one for the check whether the table that you are interested in is empty.

```
WITH MainQuery AS (
  SELECT 
  CASE WHEN EC.INV_ITEM_ID <> '' THEN EC.INV_ITEM_ID
       END AS INV_ITEM_ID
  FROM PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC
),
EmptyTableMessage AS (
  SELECT
  CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MainQuery) > 0 THEN ''
       ELSE 'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES'
       END AS EmptyMessage 
)
SELECT
EmptyTableMessage.EmptyMessage,
MainQuery.*
FROM EmptyTableMessage
LEFT OUTER JOIN MainQuery ON 1 = 1
ORDER BY MainQuery.INV_ITEM_ID
```

Feel free to change the content inside the `MainQuery` with any query that you need and change the `ORDER BY` clause at the very end according to the content of the `MainQuery`.

The negative aspect of this is that you will always have an extra column containing (as a placeholder of) the message for the empty table/record/result.

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved by using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT IIF(EC.INV_ITEM_ID <> '', EC.INV_ITEM_ID, s.col)
FROM (SELECT 'NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES') s(col)
LEFT JOIN PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC EC ON 1=1
ORDER BY EC.INV_ITEM_ID;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5d24634049e93fecf5f88c27c17e8a5d)**

---

Scenarios:

```
CREATE TABLE PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC(INV_ITEM_ID NVARCHAR(10));

-- case 1: empty value
INSERT INTO PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC VALUES ('');
-- NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES

-- case 2: empty table
TRUNCATE TABLE PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC
-- NO ITEMS IN STAGING TABLES

-- case 3: data in table
INSERT INTO PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC VALUES ('abc')
-- output: abc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is just **why** you're getting no results, here's my answer to that:

A SQL query consists of different parts called "clauses". `SELECT` and `FROM` are two of those (probably the most important ones).

Whatever you write in the `SELECT` clause (i.e. after `SELECT` and before `FROM`) can only produce **columns** from rows that are the result of what you write in the `FROM` clause. The table `PS_MASTER_ITEM_EC` in your `FROM` clause doesn't contain any rows, so your `FROM` clause can't produce any rows. Hence the `SELECT` clause doesn't have any rows that it can create columns for.

There's one exception though: If you omit the `FROM` clause, `SELECT` **can** produce a result with one single row as in

```
SELECT 'no result found' as Dummy
-- Will generate a result with one row, one column "Dummy" containing 'no result found'
```